# Linux audit files(data=)

Tags: linux, log-files, audit

`type=TTY msg=audit(08/12/2020 02:33:30.163:107) : tty pid=2709 uid=e4ws5 auid=root ses=1 major=4 minor=1 comm=sh data="/bin/bash -i",<nl>`

Can anyone tell me how in this audit.log there is a field name called data= which contains the commands that are being executed and is this a custom configuration or default in log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audit logs type **TTY** are recorded by enabling the following PAM module **pam_tty_audit.so**  on **/etc/pam.d/system-auth** or **/etc/pam.d/password-auth** to audit login shell user activity.

**data** field is included in the normal output of audit files while **pam_tty_audit.so* is enabled.

To check all **tty** messages :

```
ausearch -m tty
```